# Aptana 3 php type hierarchy

Tags: aptana3

Using Aptana Studio 3.0.6
I can't find any way to view/outline/explore the hierarchy of php classes within a project.  Code assist locates parent classes, so the introspection is happening, but if there's an actual view I can't find it.
Docs don't mention, as far as I can tell. 
Seems weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue for that at: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2207

You can add yourself as a watcher to be notified when it's done.

Cheers.